# Why is a = b rescue stmt an error but stmt rescue stmt is not?

Tags: ruby, syntax, syntax-error

I am unable to identify whats wrong with following ruby inline rescue code

```
def test_check()
p  "first st"
t = 5 * lsdj rescue return false
p "second"
end

p test_check
```

this is giving an error message  `syntax error, unexpected kFALSE, expecting kEND`
but if I remove assignment statement it will work fine(returns false).

```
 def test_check()
    p  "first st"
     5 * lsdj rescue return false
    p "second"
    end
```

If something is wrong what is the correct syntax for inline rescue in ruby.

Comment: +1. A very good question. One would have expected the modifier rule to parse identically in both cases and the answer to this gets into lots of questions about why Ruby is the way it is. Perhaps only Matz knows the full answer but I've contributed my understanding of it below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The inline `rescue` doesn't take a statement as a parameter when it is used in an assignment<sup>1,2</sup> -- it just wants a value for the expression for the case that it gets rescued.

But be careful, what do you think this will return?

```
def q
  return 5 * lsdj rescue false
  true
end
```

Not *false,* it returns *true*.  Do it this way instead so the rescue applies only to the expression.

```
def q
  return (5 * lsdj rescue false)
  true
end
```

This one returns *false.*

---

<sup>Notes.
1. It's actually a really good question. Restated:
       *Why is* **a = b rescue stmt** *an error but* **stmt rescue stmt** *is not?* 
And the superficial answer is that in the assignment case the rhs and the rescue statement are **arg** nonterminals in the ruby grammar and not full statements, whereas in the statement case the grammar simply parses a full **stmt** rule after the rescue. It's just the way it's defined. Now, if you then ask *Why is that?* ... well ... Ruby's complex grammar lives at the fringe of what **[yacc(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison)** is capable of. It looks to me like in a number of cases Matz spelled out in detail exactly what would be accepted in certain cases instead of just using a single non-terminal like *expr*, and I imagine the reason was to keep the grammar **[LALR(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR)** and to limit the inevitable [shift/reduce conflicts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift-reduce_conflict#Conflicts_in_the_constructed_tables) to tolerable space. **[Check out parse.y](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y)** in the Ruby source distribution for an interesting read. 
2. Here is an example: `def q; (t = 5 * lsdj) rescue return false; true; end` 
 this works as you wanted because it just happens to match the other grammar rule. I've heard that some of these restrictions exist in order to support poetry mode.</sup>

Comment: I searched a lot for documentation but I couldn't find any good ones.Its good explanation at the end,thanks @DigitalRoss.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will be interpreted as:

```
def test_check()
p  "first st"
t = (5 * lsdj rescue return) false
p "second"
end
```

which makes `false` being in invalid position. In order to fix it, put parentheses:

```
def test_check()
p  "first st"
t = 5 * lsdj rescue (return false)
p "second"
end
```

Comment: To be pedantic, the specific problem is that the parameter to the rescue modifier (when applied to an assignment) is the non-terminal `arg` and that simply doesn't parse a statement beginning with `keyword_return.` However, adding `(...)` causes the grammar to parse a `primary` expression, which, as it happens, does include the *return* statement.